# Cannot import static method of class using destructuring

Tags: node.js, typescript, class, import, static-methods

I'm using

- node.js: v13.11.0
- tsc: v3.8.3
- vsc: insiders-1.50.0

```
import Utils from './struct/custom/Utils';

const { connect } = Utils

console.log(connect());
```

/\ no problems

```js
import { connect } from './struct/custom/Utils';

console.log(connect());
```

/\ visual studio says: `Module '"./struct/custom/Utils"' has no exported member 'connect'. Did you mean to use 'import connect from "./struct/custom/Utils"' instead?ts(2614)`

```js
export default class Utils {
    static async connect(): Promise<Connection> {
        return (await /* some code */)
    }
}
```

/\ class definition

Comment: This question is completely unsearchable so will never benefit future users. Please include all relevant information **as text**, not in unsearchable images.

Comment: @spender, updated. sorry for that.

Comment: Is `Utils` just intended to be a bag of useful functions? You don't need to wrap them up in a class... Why not define the functions at module-level and use named exports instead? `export default` is toxic to developer tooling, among other things. https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/defaultisbad

Comment: you are right... should i delete my thread?

Comment: Even when this gets closed as a duplicate, it's still a good signpost to someone looking for the same answers.